# Writing to CSV and saving the file

Tags: python, csv

I have two programs in Python. One writes a customer's information to a CSV. The other accesses it. When the first has written it, I can open the CSV file (in Excel) and see that it has been written correctly. However for the other program to access the new data in the CSV file I have to manually open it and save it (in Excel) otherwise it doesn't work. Does anyone know why this may be?

Edit:

This writes to it (from first program):

```
f = open('details.csv', 'at', newline=''); csv_f = csv.reader(f)
csv_w.writerow(clientList)
f.close()
```

And this reads it (second program):

```
f = open('details.csv', 'rt', newline=''); csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    name.append(row[0])
```

I get this error when trying to append row[0] to a list.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Garden Centre\work.py", line 8, in <module>
    name.append(row[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a number of such problems stemming from differnt platform line endings. Under Python 2, you might try the "universal line endings" file reading mode:

```
with open('data.csv', 'rU') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print row
```

Because Excel does often use the old Mac (`\r`) and Windows (`\r\n`) standards, which can get in the `csv` module's way, esp. on a Unix or Mac platform where Python expects the Unix standard line ending (`\n`). Python 3 is generally smarter about this (and other file/string encoding issues), so generally doesn't need a special mode.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I was already on Python 3 so I'm not sure it made a difference as I'm still running into the same error.

Comment: On Python 3, IME, you're not going to see a great difference with the U mode. You will probably even get a deprecation warning. But what is that ` newline=''` parameter? That looks highly likely to be getting in your way.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer after hours of trying. In Excel, each item in an 'empty' row contains '' for the largest number of items in any row. Python doesn't write it like that to the CSV and instead only one item on an empty row contains None. As it iterated through each row, there was no first item to add to the list on the empty rows.
I had to manually add an extra '' to the list that is wrote by the first program.